# limitations of :finder_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many, table-relationships

In a rails app, I using the :finder_sql option in a has_many declaration. The rails docs say that when I do this, "find_in_collection is not added." What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it means that when you have a has_many relationship between to tables like:

person 
 has_many :books, :finder_sql

you wont get the person.books.find* methods you normaly would have gotten.
the reason for this behavior is that activerecord cant easily compose the finder_sql with the find* methods you would be using, so it cant really give you that functionality

Answer (score 3):

This means that it doesn't support the method for finding an instance within a collection. The docs call it `find_in_collection` (where "collection" is whatever the name of your association). An example might be more helpful here:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  has_many :special_posts, :class_name => "Post", 
           :finder_sql => "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ..."
end

author.find_in_posts(30)          # it finds and returns post 30
author.find_in_special_posts(30)  # not supported because finder_sql is used here.
```

Comment: Hi avit,

I'm not sure what you meant by "the method for finding an instance within a collection find_in_collection". In fact, I wasn't even sure how to parse that. Otherwise, your example would have made your answer better than Cyrik's.

Dan

Comment: Edited... hopefully that makes more sense now: I was referring to what the method was called in the docs, when it's actually a metaprogrammed method based on the name of your collection.